# How to update navbar badges in AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs

My AngularJS+Bootstrap app includes a badge in the navbar intended to give the user a count of messages awaiting their attention.  I have wrapped the navbar in its own NavController associated with the div that contains the navbar.

The main functions of my app are handled by other controllers rendered in  via a route provider, such that every page should have two controllers active: the NavController, and the controller specific to that page (e.g. Edit).  Messages get generated and queued by these other controllers.  My problem is that I cannot get the navbar badge to update to reflect the new count.

I can "cheat" and use Jquery to update the DOM directly, but that just seems wrong.

What is the "Right Way" to manage navbar state in Angular when you need it to update displays in response to state changes elsewhere in the app?

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you ways to manage global state.

First one would be to raise events, using `$emit` or `$broadcast`. I am not sure how your views are setup, but $rootScope.$broadcast just works with event broadcasting throughout the app. You can raise events that signify what happened, such as a new message got generated, message count updated. Something like
`$rootScope.$broadcast('MessageCountUpdated', {messageCount:30});`

Catch it anywhere with `$scope.$on`.

The other way is to use a service, which at any given time tracks the messages, in queue and provides useful metric that any view can bind to.

```
module.factory('MessageQueue',function(){
  var service={};
  service.queue=function(msg) {};
  service.dequeue=function() {};
  service.messageCount=function(){};
});
```

The service such as above can be injected anywhere, and can be bound to the view.